# How do you take a condition, apply it to a column, and take the values between where the condition is true and create another column based off them?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name     V  
S_1     NaN
 01      p
 02       p
S_2     NaN
 03       p
S_3     NaN
 04       p
```

I want to have the values in column "Name" that contain "S_" to be in its own column, the values that are between the "S_" values to be in its own column(lining up with the "S_" values) and the values in the "V" column to line up with the "Name" column.

So the final dataframe would look like this:

```
Name    Name2  V 
S_1     01     p
S_1     02     p
S_2     03     p
S_3     04     p
```

I know the condition statement would involve the str.contains method but I am not sure how to proceed to change the data frame to look like how I want to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mask` with `notnull`:

```
mask = df.V.notnull()
# also according to your logic
# mask = ~ df['Name'].str.startswith('S_')

df['Name1'] = df['Name'].mask(mask).ffill()
df = df[mask]
```

Output:

```
  Name  V Name1
1   01  p   S_1
2   02  p   S_1
4   03  p   S_2
6   04  p   S_3
```